# Complex Analysis Qualifying Exam Question (Schwarz Lemma?)

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I am studying for a qualifying exam in Complex Analysis and am running into some trouble with the following question.

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk $D$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $\text{Re}f(z)\le M$ on $D$, $M > 0$. Prove that $|f(z)| \le \frac{2M|z|}{1-|z|}$.

Between the domain being $D$ and $f(0)=0$, I believe Schwarz lemma is used here. However, I cannot apply it to $f$, so I've been trying to find an auxiliary function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$ and $|g|\le 1$ on the unit disk.

I'm mostly struggling with using $\text{Re}f(z)\le M$ to determine a bound for $|f|$. Could I have a hint on how to use this?

Comment: Map half-plane $\Re w<M$ to the unit disk with $0$ going to $0$ and consider the composition.